# Error when register xam.plugin.pushnotification

Tags: c#, xamarin, push-notification, xamarin.forms

I am using xam.plugin.pushnotification in my xamarin.forms project

my main activity

```cs
 protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
        ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;

        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, bundle);

        //inicializa imageCircle
        ImageCircleRenderer.Init();

        //inicializa o mapa
        global::Xamarin.FormsMaps.Init(this, bundle);

        //shared Preferences
        App.Init(new AndroidUserPreferences());

        //Gerenciador de memória
        CachedImageRenderer.Init();

        try
        {
            AppContext = this.ApplicationContext;
            CrossPushNotification.Initialize<CrossPushNotificationListener>("mysendernumbers");
            StartPushService();

            CrossPushNotification.Current.Register();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            var s = e.Message;
        }

        AndroidUserPreferences sharedPref = new AndroidUserPreferences();
        //if ( sharedPref.GetString("token") == " ")
        //{
            GetTokenTask myTask = new GetTokenTask();
            myTask.Execute(this);
        //}

        LoadApplication(new App());
    }

    public static void StartPushService()
    {
        AppContext.StartService(new Intent(AppContext, typeof(PushNotificationService)));

        if (Android.OS.Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= Android.OS.BuildVersionCodes.Kitkat)
        {

            PendingIntent pintent = PendingIntent.GetService(AppContext, 0, new Intent(AppContext, typeof(PushNotificationService)), 0);
            AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager)AppContext.GetSystemService(Context.AlarmService);
            alarm.Cancel(pintent);
        }
    }

    public static void StopPushService()
    {
        AppContext.StopService(new Intent(AppContext, typeof(PushNotificationService)));
        if (Android.OS.Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= Android.OS.BuildVersionCodes.Kitkat)
        {
            PendingIntent pintent = PendingIntent.GetService(AppContext, 0, new Intent(AppContext, typeof(PushNotificationService)), 0);
            AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager)AppContext.GetSystemService(Context.AlarmService);
            alarm.Cancel(pintent);
        }
    }
```

My listener in my pcl

```cs
public class  CrossPushNotificationListener : IPushNotificationListener
{

    public void OnMessage(JObject values, DeviceType deviceType)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Message Arrived");
    }

    public void OnRegistered(string token, DeviceType deviceType)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("Push Notification - Device Registered - Token : {0}", token));
    }

    public void OnUnregistered(DeviceType deviceType)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Push Notification - Device Unnregistered");

    }

    public void OnError(string message, DeviceType deviceType)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("Push notification error - {0}",message));
    }

    public bool ShouldShowNotification()
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

}

Registering (trying LOL) in app.cs (PCL)

```cs
 public App()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        CrossPushNotification.Current.Register();
        MainPage = new NavigationPage(new Views.Splash2());
    }
```

I am getting this error after try to register....(in onerror method)

> Java.IO.IOException: INVALID_PARAMETERS\n  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in <896ad1d315ca4ba7b117efb8dacaedcf>:0 \n  at Java.Interop.JniEnvironment+InstanceMethods.CallVoidMethod (Java.Interop.JniObjectReference instance, Java.Interop.JniMethodInfo method, Java.Interop.JniArgumentValue* args) [0x00069] in <25999cc1fde6426b852c2e027711c254>:0 \n  at Android.Runtime.JNIEnv.CallVoidMethod (System.IntPtr jobject, System.IntPtr jmethod, Android.Runtime.JValue* parms) [0x0000e] in <7a2bbe1fcaec4467930361ae212aeea9>:0 \n  at Android.Gms.Gcm.GcmPubSub.Subscribe (System.String registrationToken, System.String topic, Android.OS.Bundle extras) [0x00096] in <442f26a0595046369060be9502394e67>:0 \n  at PushNotification.Plugin.PushNotificationRegistrationIntentService.SubscribeTopics (System.String token) [0x00023] in <06cf100f14f94017b47f90010ef822f3>:0 \n  at PushNotification.Plugin.PushNotificationRegistrationIntentService.OnHandleIntent (Android.Content.Intent intent) [0x0004a] in <06cf100f14f94017b47f90010ef822f3>:0 \n  --- End of managed Java.IO.IOException stack trace ---\njava.io.IOException: INVALID_PARAMETERS\n\tat com.google.android.gms.iid.zzc.zzb(Unknown Source)\n\tat com.google.android.gms.iid.zzc.zza(Unknown Source)\n\tat com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID.zzc(Unknown Source)\n\tat com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID.getToken(Unknown Source)\n\tat com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmPubSub.subscribe(Unknown Source)\n\tat md563bb5d7cd114ceda82ec85fb57ce3637.PushNotificationRegistrationIntentService.n_onHandleIntent(Native Method)\n\tat md563bb5d7cd114ceda82ec85fb57ce3637.PushNotificationRegistrationIntentService.onHandleIntent(PushNotificationRegistrationIntentService.java:37)\n\tat android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:65)\n\tat android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)\n\tat android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)\n\tat android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)\n - Register - PushNotificationRegistationIntentService

Answer (score 0):

I guess its not the exact answer you've been looking for, but this package you, me and many others are using, was recently announced as [DEPRECATED](https://github.com/BDBPayroll/xamarin-plugins/blob/master/PushNotification/README.md).
If you ain't public with PushNotifications yet you should strongly consider migration.